# asp.net ajax updatepanel will not fire in IE or chrome in usercontrol

Tags: .net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

Hey there ive browsed for some hours now for this problem and can't find anything on it.

im having an updatepanel inside an ASCX file which will not do anything in IE and Chrome(in Firefox 3 it works 100%). Its supposed to do a few serversided checks on the content then send a mail and give the user a message in a label.

im using a masterpage where my scriptmanager is(nothing fancy) :

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Inside a page i envoke my ascx file where there is an updatepanel that looks like this.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Always"
                runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <textarea id="helpSenderComment" name="comment" runat="server"></textarea>
                    <p>
                        <span id="helpSenderA" runat="server"></span>+<span id="helpSenderB" runat="server"></span>=<input
                            id="helpSenderAnswer" runat="server" type="text" /></p>
                    <p id="helpSenderError" runat="server" class="error">
                    </p>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Its really quite simpel and it works in FF, but in internet explorer and chrome i can see that its not even firing the event.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't use triggers, remove the elements

Comment: i don't understand your comment about removing the elements(maybe im slow on this monday morning :) ) Ive added a trigger but still it dosnt give anything for IE or Chrome                                                                   
                
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
                </Triggers>

Comment: I am sorry I am late. I meant, if you don't use triggers in your code, then just remove the triggers elements. In the code you posted you have this <Triggers></Triggers>, remove it as it expected for something which it never declared.